# Is it posible to use npm in marketing cloud pages?

Tags: marketing-cloud, node.js, node-salesforce

I know NPM is made to use of JS packages in node.js environment.
But I was wondering, is there a way to install packages in MC so I can require() in cloud pages?

Answer (score 1):

Nodejs requires a runtime so you cannot use the packages directly but you  can use `browserify` to make those packages run in browser or you can use any other web module loader in cloud pages.